# Using redis as cache as REST Api user (in order to save Api requests)

Tags: node.js, rest, api, caching, redis

I am a API user and I have only a limited number of requests availble for a high traffic website (~1k concurrent visitors). In order to save API requests I would like to cache the responses for specific requests which are unlikely to change.

However I want to refresh this redis key (the API response) at least every 15 seconds. I wonder what the best approach for this would be?

**My ideas:**

- I thought the TTL field would be handy for this scenario. Just set a TTL of 15s for this key. When I query this key and it's not present I would just request it again using the API. **The problem:** Since this is a high traffic website I would expect around 20-30 requests until I've got a response from the API and this would lead to 20-30 requests to the API within a few ms. So I would need to "pause" all incoming requests until there is a API response
- My second idea was to refresh the key every 15s. I could set a background task which runs every 15s or upon page request I could check in my controller if the key needs a refresh. I would prefer the last idea but therefore I would need to maintain the redis key age and this seems to be very expensive and it is not a built in feature?

What would you suggest for this use case?

**My controller code:**

```
function players(req, res, next) {
    redisClient.getAsync('leaderboard:players').then((playersLeaderboard) => {
        if(!playersLeaderboard) {
            // We need to get a fresh copy of the playersLeaderboard
        }

        res.set('Cache-Control', 's-maxage=10, max-age=10')
        res.render('leaderboards/players', {playersLeaderboard: playersLeaderboard})
    }).catch((err) => {
        logger.error(err)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply fetch and cache the data when the node.js server starts and then set an interval for 15 seconds to fetch fresh data and update cache. Avoid using the TTL for this usecase.

```
function fetchResultsFromApi(cb) {
   apiFunc((err, result) => {
        // do some error handling
       // cache result in redis without ttl
       cb();
    });
}

fetchResultsFromApi(() => {
    app.listen(port);
    setInterval(() => {
        fetchResultsFromApi(() => {});
    }, 15000);
}
```

**Pros:**

1. Very simple to implement
2. No queuing of client request required
3. Super fast response times

**Cons:**

1. The cache update might not execute/complete exactly after every 15th second. It might be a few milliseconds here and there. I assume that it won't make a lot of difference for what you are doing and you can always reduce the interval time to update cache before 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is more of an architecture question than those typical "help my code don't work" kind.

Let me paraphrase your requirements.

**Q:** I would like to cache the responses of some HTTP requests which are unlikely to change and I would like these cached responses to be refreshed every 15 seconds. Is it possible?

**A:** Yes it is and you're so going to thank the fact that `Javascript` is single threaded so it is going to be quite straight forward.

Some fundamental knowledge here. `NodeJS` is an event driven framework which means that at 1 point in time it is going to execute only one piece of code, all the way until it is done.

If any `aysnc` call is encountered along the way, it will call them and add an event to the `event-loop` to say "`callback` when a response is received". When the code routine is finished then it will pops the next event from the queue to run them.

Based on this knowledge, we know we can achieve this by building a `function` to only fire-off 1 async call to `update` the `cached-responses` everytime it expires. If an async call is already in action, then just put their callback functions into a queue. This is so that you don't do multiple async calls to fetch the new result.

I'm not familiar with the `async` module so I have provided an pseudo code example using `promises` instead.

**Pseudo code:**

```
var fetch_queue = [];
var cached_result = {
    "cached_result_1": {
        "result" : "test",
        "expiry" : 1501477638 // epoch time 15s in future
    }
}

 var get_cached_result = function(lookup_key) {
    if (cached_result.hasOwnProperty(lookup_key)) {
        if (result_expired(cached_result[lookup_key].expiry)) {
            // Look up cached
            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                 resolve(cached_result[lookup_key].result);
            });
        }
        else {
            // Not expired, safe to use cached result
            return update_result();
        }
    }

}

var update_result = function() {
    if (fetch_queue.length === 0) {
        // No other request is retrieving an updated result.
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            // call your API to get the result.
            // When done call.
            resolve("Your result");

            // Inform other requests that an updated response is ready.
            fetch_queue.forEach(function(promise) {
                promise.resolve("Your result");
            })

            // Compute the new expiry epoch time and update the cached_result
        })
    }
    else {
        // Create a promise and park it into the queue
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            fetch_queue.push({
                resolve: resolve,
                reject: reject
            })
        });
    }
}

get_cached_result("cached_result_1").then(function(result) {
    // reply the result
})
```

**Note:** As the name suggested the code is not actual working solution but the concept is there.

Something worth noting is, `setInterval` is 1 way to go **but** it doesn't guarantee that the function will get called exactly at the 15 second mark. The API only make sure that something will happen after the expected time.

Whereas the proposed solution will ensure that as long as the `cached result` has expired, the very next person looking it up will do a request and the following requests will wait for the initial request to return.